# How to maximize a JFrame through code?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, maximize

How to maximize a JFrame through code?

Comment: Did you try looking at the methods defined for JFrame and its super classes?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes sir, I did and it's too complicated for my ickle brains.

Comment: Heres a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207711).

Comment: See also the answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55592409/243373).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try this:

```
f.setExtendedState( f.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
```

Comment: I found the same after googling. However the above code does not work with newer versions of Java.

Comment: `JFrame` doesn't have that member... `MAXIMIZED_WHATEVER`.

Comment: @Tony: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: @Harry: Any alternative that will work for machines other than yours?

Comment: @Tony: are you setting `f.setResizable(false);`? if yes then it will not work. Show some of your code for better understanding.

Comment: @Harry: They have moved the constant `MAXIMIZED_WHATEVER` from `JFrame` to `java.awt.Frame`. That one change solved my problem. I suggest you update your answer as well. Thanks.

Comment: @TonyOgrewall yes but afaik its inherited from `Frame` into `JFrame` so you can still use it.

Comment: it work only after setVisible(true) in my case(windows 8.1). so i override setVisible function for showing JFrame with maximized state.

Comment: Make sure this is set AFTER making the `frame.setVisible(true)`

Answer (score 8):

this works perfectly till java 7

```
public class TEST
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame jf= new JFrame();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yea the Toolkit solution ignores the windows task bar and uses the full screen which is not what you want.

For an immediate maximise of your form just add this in the `JFrame` constructor after the `InitiateComponents()` call.

```
this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

The class extends `JFrame` of course:

```
public class MyForm extends javax.swing.JFrame
```

Answer (score 3):

setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); is not working is java 7

You can try this code it works.

```
     Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();  
     int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());  
     int ySize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());  
     setSize(xSize,ySize);
```

Comment: hmm ... MAXIMIZED_BOTH just works fine for me, in any recent version. What's your OS? BTW: the problem with manual sizing is that the taskbar isn't accounted for (at least not reliably)

Comment: better use setPreferredSize

Answer (score 1):

for similar problems with:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7177173

An issue on jdk7. Try to call .setExtendedState() not directly after .setVisable()