# How to split a frame into views with multiple lines

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea, jtextpane

I'm doing this program with `NetBeans` and I need: 
a `Frame` with a split view, fitting the frame's width, each view has multiple lines, where I `add/remove` strings, these strings can have a particular font and colors.

Can you provide me some examples or which classes should I use to resolve the problem ?

Thanks @trashgod, this is gonna really help me. About the layouts, i've build in netbeans a jframe that it expands to the full resolution of the screen in use, and inside of it i'd want ,as you suggested to me, 2 JTextPane half the jframe's width side by side that resize themselves when the jframe expands...until now i tried setSize() and setPreferredSize() on each JTextPane, but so far nothing...any idea why isn't working? here's my code

```
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int width = (int)screenSize.getWidth();
    int height = (int)screenSize.getHeight();
    System.out.println(width +" x "+ height);
    this.setSize(width,height);
    Dimension dimTextArea1 = new Dimension((width/2),height);
    Dimension dimTextArea2 = new Dimension((width/2),height);
    jTextPane1.setPreferredSize(dimTextArea1);
    jTextPane2.setPreferredSize(dimTextArea2);
```

Comment: Did you look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) ?

Comment: Yeah, but i didn't find what i was looking for. I'm new about graphics and all that i have found was jSplitpane, jTextArea and jTextPane. But it seems to me, that each one is missing one of my requirements.

Comment: Start with [Creating a UI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and have a look at [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to use lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `StyledDocument` in a `JTextPane`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15600689/230513), usng any of a variety of [layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

[image]

Addendum: *I'd want…half the frame's width side-by-side that resize themselves when the frame expands…I tried* `setSize()` *and* `setPreferredSize()`.

*Don't* use [`setPreferredSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513). *Do* add your two text panes to a `GridLayout(1, 0)`, which means "one row & some arbitrary number of columns". After `pack()`, use `setExtendedState()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5207711/230513).

Comment: If you need additional guidance, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you encountered and comment here.

Comment: Last question (i hope). Once i add these formatted strings, i need also to remove some of them from JTextPane. Do i need JTextPane or StyledDocument ? Isn't there something easier to add/remove styled strings from a text area?  Thanks a lot, you're a big help.

Comment: `StyledDocument` is the _model_; `JTextPane` is a _view_ of that _model_. Many components [accept limited HTML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html).